# What user-friendly VPN software is available?

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, networking, vpn

Other than the Network Manager applet at the Natty panel, is there any other user-friendly VPN tool available. One which has a GUI and can be easily setup.

Ref. question : [ConnMan not detecting already existing wireless network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41440/connman-not-detecting-already-existing-wireless-network/42677#42677)

Comment: Native to gnome? Or any kind of VPN? I have listed a few here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42422/desktop-sharing-outside-empathy/42443#42443

Comment: May I ask why? Why do you want another too other than Network Manager and the built-in VPN support.

Comment: @RinzWind: Thanks for the link. I am looking for a VPN tool preferably on native Gnome.

Comment: @user4124:I am looking for a tool because I am not using Network Manager, thus not getting the built-in support for VPN connection. As because I am using Wicd, I need some other tool to get connected to the VPN services. You can please refer to the link shared in my question to know more about why I removed Gnome NetworkManager. In short, everytime I boot my system and router, although Network manager was saying that I am connected, in actual I was not connected. So I had to add the network again to get the connection working. As suggested in the post I tried Wicd and finally that worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubuntu has KVpnc as described [here](http://home.gna.org/kvpnc/en/index.html).

If you dont mind the QT type interface, its a nice gui vpn client that can be installed on a Gnome/Unity interface - search for kvpnc.

[image]

Googling around - there is a suggested gnome friendly vpn client with a similar name "[gvpnc](http://code.google.com/p/gvpnc/)" - havent seen any reviews for this though.

[image]

Comment: @fossfreedom: Thanks for suggesting the tools. Because I am on GNome, I will try gvpnc.

Comment: @fossfreedom: I installed gvpnc but for some reason no UI is showing and also there is no message about whether the VPN is connected or not. Is there any .deb available which works for Natty?

Comment: Arindom - I followed the suggestions in the README file i.e. sudo apt-get install vpnc   add "cd <folder name" to gvpnc, copy "sample..." to /etc/vpnc/gvpnc.conf (you are supposed to edit some details in this newly created file)  and then started the application  ./gvpnc.  I dont have a VPN to connect to, so I cant test.

Comment: Fossfreedom - I also followed the instructions but when I started the application ./gvpnc apparently nothing happened, because I was returned to the prompt immediately without any error message or the GUI. I must have made some mistakes in the .conf file. I will try again.

Comment: The good news is after installing/re-installing of different networking tools, strangely it may sound, but the actual issue is solved now! Because I need to connect to the VPN connection, I thought of reinstalling gnome networking manager and removed wicd. Upon reboot of my PC and router there is no problem I can now connect to the network without the need to add the wireless network again (which was the original issue). I thank everyone here for helping with different ideas.

Comment: I am not sure why it worked now, but it seems (from my perspective of just an User), some configuration file might have got corrected during this process, which helped the networking manager to now get connected to the Internet.